# https undefined in react native axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, https, axios

I have used axios for react native app but while implementing https.agent it shows https is undefined. How to solve this?
 My code

```
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});

 instance.get('https://example.com');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
    axios.post('/practz/login', {
          "username" :"orgadmin1@example.com",
          "password":"exam",
          "appId":"AABBCD",
          "domainName":"example.com",
          httpsAgent: agent
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: Have you imported 'https', `const https = require('https');` ?

Comment: yes, https not found

Comment: ok, have you installed it. `$ npm install https`?

Comment: yes i have installed

Comment: This is not going to work as you're not in a node environment.
Axios Documentation says this : 

`httpAgent` and `httpsAgent` define a custom agent to be used when performing http and https requests, respectively, in node.js. This allows options to be added like `keepAlive` that are not enabled by default.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20488) where you can find resources to get your requests to https work.
Or [here](https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce/issues/136)

Comment: @Drench & mrkpatchaa 
did you get solution? please post solution here. I am stuck in same issue from last 2 days.

Answer (score -2):

This is problem with Android 9 or 10, you have to add SSLCertificateChainFile in Apache configuration.

`SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server-ca.crt"`

Then it will be working fine